# When using mutiple router-outlets, can't find route when using router's navigate method

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, router-outlet

I have an application that has a router-outlet in my app.component.html, but 
 a nest component called EventDetailsComponent I would like to have another router-outlet with two children routes.

Simply i just need a component( EventDetailsComponent)  that has its own view but also 2 sub views that can be routed to. When the parent/children components are initialized i wouild navigated to the createSession component by default

The issue I am having is when I try to navigate in the method addSession() I get this error:

`error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'events/2'`

I don't have this issue when use routerLink directive on a button or anchor tag, like this : `<button [routerLink]="['/events/2', {outlets: {'nav': ['session']}}]"></button>`

```
    export class EventDetailsComponent {


      constructor(private eventService:EventService,
                  private router: Router, private route: ActivateRoute) {
      }


      addSession() {
        this.router.navigate(['/events',2, {outlets: {'nav': ['session']}}]);
      }

    }
```

**eventDetailComponent.html**

```
    <div>
         <router-outlet name="nav"></router-outlet>
     </div>
```

**in Routes.ts loaded in app.module**

```
    export const appRoutes:Routes = [
      { path: 'events', component: EventsListComponent }, 
      { path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailsComponent, resolve: {event: EventResolver}, children:[
        {path:'event', component: createEvent, outlet:'nav' },
        {path:'session', component: createSession, outlet:'nav' }
      ] }
    ]
```

I would really like to know how to properly provide the parameters for the router.navigate() when using router-outlet. Especially why providing the parent route '/events, 2,...' isn't found? Any ideas would be most appreciated